# How To Add an Underline Border to a UITextField When it is a SubView of ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield, subview

I am trying to programmatically create an underline border for a UITextfield when it is a subview of a UIScrollView in my iOS app built with Swift. I have managed to achieve this but only when the UITextfield is a subview of the view as the following screenshot of my app shows.

[UITextfield with an Underline Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiiSV.png)

Now I would like the UITextField to be a subview of a UIScrollView within the same view but the underline border does not show.

I successfully managed to create the underline border in the screenshot above by creating a CALayer in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method as follows.

```
    let usernameTextField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        usernameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(usernameTextField)
        let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        usernameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
        usernameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        usernameTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            let textField = usernameTextField
            let border = CALayer()
            let width = CGFloat(1.0)
            border.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.61, green:0.61, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

            border.borderWidth = width

            textField.layer.addSublayer(border)

            textField.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
```

But this won't work when the UITextField is a subview of a UIScrollView. This is what I have tried:

```
    let usernameTextField = UITextField()
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    usernameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(usernameTextField)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    let scrollViewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
    ]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(scrollViewConstraints)
    let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
    usernameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        usernameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
        usernameTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor) 
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
  }

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let textField = usernameTextField
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.61, green:0.61, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width

        textField.layer.addSublayer(border)

        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to make this work when the UITextField is a subview of a UIScrollView within the same view?

**EDIT**

I have accepted Matthias' answer where he has suggested I SubView a UIView as a border instead of a SubLayer.

```
    let border = UIView()
    border.backgroundColor =UIColor(red:0.61, green:0.61, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0)
            border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    textField.addSubview(border)

        border.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
        border.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:textField.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        border.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: -1).isActive = true
        border.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

This answers the question but just of curiosity I'd appreciate anyone who could also explain if it is possible to achieve the same with a SubLayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a subLayer, try just adding a subview :)

```
    let border = UIView()
border.backgroundColor =UIColor(red:0.61, green:0.61, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0)
                border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

textField.addSubview(border)

            border.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
            border.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:textField.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            border.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: -1).isActive = true
            border.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Great. The border is showing. To help others, you might want to remove the cgColor since border is just a UIView and not a CALayer. But your answer worked.